# getting current line text is on

Tags: c#, textbox, lines

I have a list of lines that looks like this:

```
textbox.text += "p"+b+" the rest\r\np"+b+" more text";
```

b is supposed to represent the current line number in the textbox that the line is on. I have tried using textbox.lines.count() but it only changes i into the last line number.

Is there any other way about going with this, or do I have to switch to another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I split the lines by the line breaks ("\r\n") and used a for loop to replace "b" (I changed it to string rather than a variable)

```
for (int i = 0; i < da.Length; i++)
                {
                    //replace char with number
                    string f = da[i].Replace("n", (i + 1).ToString());
                    disp.Text += f + "v";
                }
```

I added "v" so that I can replace it outside of the loop with "\r\n" again.

Answer (score 2):

If you are assigning, I think you can do it manually (calculate the line number). There is no function that could "guess" on which line the tex will appear.
You can create a integer variable and increment it when appending a line/s and use the variable when you need to display the current line number.

Comment: For using an integer variable and incrementing it, is that a for loop? Also, more lines of text are added using a button, so I don't think I can manually calculate the number.

Comment: You have to mantain a global variable or class member variable and use it. You can use not only the for loop, but also while loop or simply increase the veriable manually by one. I don't know exactly what you code is doing, but one of these scenarios should be get choice. The button click will use the same variable, or you can use the current line count using textbox.lines.count.